# Drupal 8: Is it possible to get title from path or route name?

Tags: drupal, routes, title, drupal-8

Is it possible to get Title of a page from the url or route name.

I have a router name for example: ***view.topics_landing_page.page***

Or the same page has a path: **/topics**
By using either path or Route name, I wants to get the title Eg:- Topics.

Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get the page title of any URL/route would be to actually request the page and see what the title is. The reason is that any module or the theme could alter the title from what it normally would be, like fx metatags module.

To get the title of the current page you could do this:

```
use \Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface;

$request = \Drupal::request();
if ($route = $request->attributes->get(RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
  $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route); 
}
```

But another thing you could do is override the [breadcrumb.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21breadcrumb.html.twig/8.2.x) template. This will render the template wherever you place the Breadcrumb block.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 has core functionality for page title.

In block structure you can see "Page Title" [Link : your-domain/admin/structure/block]

You can use this one on any region you want to show title of current page.
Clear you cache after set this block on region..!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know that. But What I am looking for is different. I am creating a breadcrumb where I wants to get title of a different page from its url or route name, not current from current page url, but from that pages url.